# iphone : click on google Admob restarts the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, admob

I have integrated `google Admob` in my app. And when I try to click on that banner of Ad it `restarts the device`

When it gets restart it shows dialog box which says
`SpringBoard has just crashed`

`It is working fine with simulator.`

On Console it shows exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'SBAppToAppTransitionView should only be used on devices with fast color multiply'
```

Device I am testing on is `iPhone 3G 4.2.1`

Comment: My bet is that this is yet another anti-google maneuver by Apple...

on another note:
On the case of iPhone Development, I've noticed that things always run fine in the simulator... when you pass it to the actual device, they tend to have some problems...

Comment: also, on an added note:
what iPhone are you using? because that error pretty much points out to an old version... try compiling your code to that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that would force the device to restart. You can hook your device up to the USB and run Organizer / Console for your device, and see if there is anything abnormal in there. If the device is automatically restarting, I would also doubt there would be any crash output, so the console while right before the device restarts may give you some indication as to why.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error on my phone every time an app tried to transition to another app (in-app purchases, for example).

My phone is an iPhone 3G, Jailbroken, running iOS 4.2.1.
I did not have the problem when running an earlier iOS 3.x.x version.

The solution I found came from this link: http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=323402

Adding the key:

> `<key>opengles-2</key> 
>  <true/>`

to  /System/Library/CoreServices/Springboard.app allowed SBAppToAppTransitionView to display the "page flip" animation and switch apps without crashing Springboard.

The page flipping animation seems to work just fine on an iPhone 3GS (which supports native multitasking) without any tweaks.

This probably won't help you directly when you publish your app, but will hopefully pinpoint you to the location of the problem and let you work around it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That dialog box is the Classic mobilesubstrate dialog box, that means that the springboard crashed with SIG*** exception ;)